# Ubuntu 22.04 on MacBook Pro 2019 (16-inch)

Tags: boot, macbook

I want to dual boot ubuntu 22.04 on my MacBook Pro 2019 16-inch (macOS Monterey Version 12.6).
I already tried to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive.

My steps:

1.MacBook Pro T2 chip --> Set external boot to: Allow booting from external media

2.Create a new partition (FAT/FAT32)

3.Reformat the USB stick using Apple's "Disk Utility" --> Set the format to MS-DOS (FAT) and the scheme to GUID Partition Map.

4.Install Balena Etcher

5.Install Ubuntu ISO file 22.04 version

6.Start Balena Etcher and write the iso file into the usb drive

7.Restart the MacBook and hold option to launch the boot menu

8.Select EFI usb drive (orange color)

After step 8 i noticed 2 things:

With iso Ubuntu 22.04 --> the EFI usb drive (orange color) not showing up

With iso Ubuntu 22.10 --> the EFI usb drive (orange color) show up, but this warning appear: The version of macOs on the selected disk needs to be reinstalled. Use recovery to reinstalled macOs or select another startup disk : https://ibb.co/Mgsphry

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Installing a bare-metal Linux distro on a 2019 MacBook Pro is no walk in the park. You’re going to find that a bunch of things don’t work quite right. The battery life will be almost nothing, the fans will always run because the machine is hot, the SSDs will run at half their rated speed, the wifi will be slow, the Bluetooth won’t work, and the TouchBar will be even more out of place … which will essentially remove any Escape key you might think you have. A VM is really the most effective way to run Ubuntu (or any Linux distro) on that machine 

Comment: Ok I will try VM. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my mac Air 9,1 (late 2020), works most of it, and unlike Apple made it look, it's possible to have dual boot without any hack.

First, you need to fully disable secure boot, you can do it holding command +  R to enter your UEFI settings, and disable all secure boot functions.

Just boot into [Ubuntu T2](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu/releases/tag/v6.2.5-1) Live ISO, first try all it out, if most of things works, there's guides for those who don't.

When ready, go to install Ubuntu (use a new SSD please) and go next, when asked how do you want to install, select other, locate your SSD UNIT, and make a partition to ExT4 mounting to /.

When selecting the UEFI partition, just select the internal NVME, I don't know if it's Ubuntu or Apple or both, but it's smart enough to create a separate folder for ubuntu (in my case) but still have it's Apple folder.

I know you already messed up a little, but when you recover, you can do this step by step and easly install it.

Well, first kudos for people at https://t2linux.org, they did an amazing job.  Mine's working very well, use my answer as you own risk, but I'm here to help. Wish you luck on your journey my friend :)